# Why this goroutines are asleep?

Tags: go

In my opinion,the "select...case" means "If any chan is available, it executes".So,Why are there error here ,I think `message<-msg` is available chan send , but it cause **deadlock!**. thanks very much.

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    messages:=make(chan string)
    //signals:=make(chan string)

    select {
    case msg:=<-messages:
        fmt.Println(msg)
    default:
        fmt.Println("no mes receivedd")
    }

    msg:="h1"
    select {
    case messages<-msg:
        fmt.Println("sent message",msg)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first select has a `default` case, so it selected that immediately. The second select attempts to write to `messages`, but there are no other goroutines listening, so you have a deadlock.

Move the second select before the first, put it in a goroutine, and remove the `default` case, then you'll have a successful send/receive.

Comment: thanks , I have a successful send&receive by you teaching,but why I need put  second select in a **goroutine** ? I try this but it still deadlock `package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
 messages:=make(chan string)
 //signals:=make(chan string)

 msg:="h1"
 select {
 case messages<-msg:
  fmt.Println("sent message",msg)
 }

 select {
 case msg:=<-messages:
  fmt.Println(msg)
 default:
  fmt.Println("no mes receivedd")
 }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

[image]
source [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/channel-in-golang/)

> Here we have two goroutines map with two functions. one goroutine map
> with main function and one with an anonymous function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    messages := make(chan string)
    //signals:=make(chan string)
    msg := "h1"
    go func(msg string) {
        select {
        case messages <- msg:
            fmt.Println("sent message", msg)
        }
    }(msg)

    select {
    case msg := <-messages:
        fmt.Println("Message recieved", msg)
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/rBbfBxuMe4R)</kbd>